# Инициализация переменной в функции

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Всем привет. У меня есть класс для авторизации пользователя, в котором находится переменная int id пользователя. Мне надо использовать ее в другом классе, я получаю ее по указателю и все хорошо работает. Проблема в том, что инициализировать эту переменную мне надо в функции, которая вызывается при нажатии на кнопку входа при заполненных полях логина и пароля. Т.е все происходит так: Данные-с-полей--->кнопка-ВХОД--->получение-строки-из-БД-по-введенному-логину--->инициализация-id.
Каким образом можно передать это значение в другой класс по указателю?

```
    // login_form.cpp

Login_Form::Login_Form(...) 
...
{
    ...

    DataBaseConnection(); 

    connect(ui->login_enter, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (ifLoginCorrect()));

   Если задать user_id здесь, то все норм
   // user_id = 7771;

}

// но нужно брать значение отсюда
void Login_Form::ifLoginCorrect() {

    login_value = ui->login_field->text(); 
    pswd_value = ui->password_field->text();

    ...
    //Здесь получаю переменную user_id
     current_query.exec("SELECT id FROM students WHERE login=\'" + login_value + "\'");
     while(current_query.next()) {
         QString u_id = current_query.value(0).toString();
         user_id = u_id.toInt();
         qDebug() << "LOGIN User id is: " << user_id << endl;
     }
}
// login_form.h
...
public:
    int *user_id_ptr = &user_id;
...
private:
    int user_id = 0;

// второй класс
// user_window.cpp

#include "user_window.h"
#include "ui_user_window.h"
#include <login_form.h>


User_Window::User_Window(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::User_Window)
{
    .....
        connect(op_button, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (ifSubjectDone()));

    }

void User_Window::ifSubjectDone() {

    ......

    c2 = new Login_Form();
    ptr = c2->user_id_ptr;

    qDebug() << "Now user ID: " << *ptr << endl;

}

// user_window.h

private slots:
    void ifSubjectDone();

private:
    Login_Form* c2;
    int *ptr;
```

Comment: минимальный какой-нибудь пример кода можно увидеть?

Comment: @МихаилРебров добавил код

Comment: А где другой класс? В коде вижу только `Login_Form`. В этом случае достаточно ограничиться одной переменной-членом `user_id`. Добавлять публичный указатель, который ссылается на закрытые данные - это совсем плохая затея.

Comment: @alexolut добавил второй класс

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того как ведёт себя или как должна вести себя программа, можно решить проблему по разному. Как понимаю Login_Form получает/заполняет данные о пользователе, тогда в месте где нужно получить от этой формы user_id просто дожидаешься точки когда форма уже все данные получила и тогда получаешь этот айди, хорошо кстати получение оформить в виде метода GetUserId() тогда в этом методе можно выждать паузу пока данные не пришли и только тогда возвратить нужный айди. Если ждать сразу нет возможности тогда нужно чтобы `bool GetUserId(int & user_id)` возвращало например true/false если уже данные есть или нет и только если вернуло true тогда user_id можно считать заполненым нужной величиной. Т.е. нужно где-то хранить форму и её иногда опрашивать чтобы получить нужные от неё данные, при этом можно либо блокирующий сделать GetUserId() который дожидается ввода либо не блокирующий который флаг успеха вернёт. При этом обязательно пока все данные не получены где-то эта форма хранится в виде переменной или члена класса. Ваше решение когда сохраняется указатель на user_id небезопасно, кто знает живой ли объект формы или уже не живой, т.е. указатель может быть действительным или нет. Зато если хранится объект формы всё время пока она не выполнила нужные действия тогда есть гарантия, что все её методы будут работать.

Если же всё равно нужно как-то с указателем решить эту проблему, тогда это тоже решаемо, только не так как в коде у вас, а так - нужно умный указатель использовать например std::shared_ptr, т.е. в классе формы мы не храним два члена (int user_id и int * ptr_user_id), а храним один член std::shared_ptr ptr_user_id, в конструкторе под него выделяем память ptr_user_id = new int(0), потом когда нужно в форме заполняем его при этом также из формы его сделаем возможным для получения через `shared_ptr<int> GetUserIdPtr() const { return ptr_user_id; }`. Во всех местах где нужно потребить этот айди просто копируем себе в свой член класса shared_ptr my_copy_user_id; ... после создания формы делаем `my_copy_user_id = form.GetUserId()` и теперь у нас в форме и в потребителях у всех shared_ptr указывающий на одну общую память, в итоге потом можно получать значение указателя в любой момент, даже когда формы объект уничтожен, при этом будет безопасно, тажке можно всегда проверять заполнелся ли user_id уже значением или ещё нет, если 0 значит ещё не заполнился, иначе заполнился. shared_ptr это стандартный С++ шаблонный класс который подсчитывает ссылки на общую память заданного типа и сам когда надо освобождает её т.е. ничего для освобождения не нужно делать, также подсчёт ссылок гарантирует что память освободится только когда форма и все её потребители завершат своё существование. Также когда форма уже уничтожена при этом указатель остаётся валидным т.к. память под него не уничтожается.